# How to get all interfaces implemented by a class in the editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Is there any method (best would be a key chord) in VS2013 (C#) to determine all the interfaces the given class implements? Something like `typeof(ClassNameUnderCursor).GetInterfaces();` performed by IntelliSense or VS itself?

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't.

You have `Go To Definition (F12)` but you will have to do the breakdown yourself.

Comment: True. If you really want to, you can create an own VSIX addin that does this for you. But you will have to develop it yourself. (maybe someone did already, but not that I am aware of).